# Accessing system views in master database in SQL Server using readonly user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a user in SQL server who can only access to 2 databases in readonly mode so I have assigned to this user the role db_datareader.

Now I need this user to have access to system views in master database in order to perform below query:

```
select * FROM sys.databases sd LEFT JOIN sys.sysprocesses sp ON sd.database_id = sp.dbid 
WHERE database_id = 6 AND LOGINAME IS NOT NULL
```

So I have granted access to master database using db_datareader role so user can only have readonly access over this database.

Furthermore, I needed to grant sysadmin server role in master database in order to this query to work for this user. I wonder if this is the correct way to do it. Or is there any other better way to do it? Granting sysadmin server role sounds not good...

**UPDATE**:

I have created below stored procedure. If I log into Sql Server Management Studio using readonly user and I call the stored procedure as below I get a message error:

```
exec [mySchema].[spGetNumberOfCurrentConnections] 


CREATE PROCEDURE [mySchema].[spGetNumberOfCurrentConnections] 
WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo'
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select * FROM sys.databases sd LEFT JOIN sys.sysprocesses sp ON sd.database_id = sp.dbid 
    WHERE database_id = 6 AND LOGINAME IS NOT NULL
END
```

**ERROR**:

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'spGetNumberOfCurrentConnections', database 'myDatabase', schema 'mySchema'.
```

**UPDATED 2**:

I have granted EXECUTE permission on stored procedure for readonly user. Now stored procedure executes but it is returning 1 only row which is not correct since it should return at least 100 rows.

I have granted permission to user over stored procedure as indicated in the image:

[image]

Since the readonly user account does not have the 'sysadmin' role it is just showing a single row.

If I set the 'sysadmin' role for the readonly user account it shows all the rows (not a single row as before).

Comment: Making an account `sysadmin` means they can do anything and the membership in the `db_datareader` role is pointless. Consider making a stored procedure to retrieve specific data you need using `EXECUTE AS` and/or certificates. See [this](http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) for a more thorough discussion.

Comment: Why have you tagged 3 different versions of SQL Server (2 of which are completely out of support)?

Comment: @Larnu just because a release is out of support does not mean customers are no longer using it.  I guarantee you there is a larger percentage of users still on SQL2008 than you think.

Comment: I didn't say people aren't using it @Greg (it's actually shocking how many are still using it, and even more shocking the amount that are unaware it isn't supported), but the fact is the OP *has* tagged 3 different versions here. 2012's functionality is quite different to 2008(R2)'s, and hence why i asked.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have updated my post, I have created a store procedure and I try to execute it using 'execute as ' but I get the error indicated.

Comment: You still need to explicitly grant permission to execute the stored procedure (`GRANT EXECUTE ON ... TO ... `) to accounts/roles that you want to be able to use this; that replaces granting `sysadmin` permissions. Also, do not use `sp` as a prefix for stored procedures, it's reserved to the system and it has [real impact](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have granted EXECUTE permission on stored procedure for the readonly user. Now the SP executes but it only returns 1 row instead of returning a lot more.... I have updated the post again. see it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting ViEW SERVER STATE permission for the readonly user works.

The problem was that user was only seeing the current session, not all the executing sessions on the SQL Server instance.